# My AdMob ads do not show while USB debugging in Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, admob

Recently I noticed that my AdMob ads do not show. It occurs while debugging app on USB. Why such thing happens, everything is correct in my code.

```
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
}
```

Comment: I read once that ads are disabled while you debug. Obviously to prevent you generating revenue against yourself

Comment: what error you see in logs?

Answer (score 0):

try by putting this into your code may be helpful.

```
 MobileAds.initialize(this, "YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID");
```

above your ad initialization
use this id for testing  place of  "YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID"

```
 ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713
```